# How to translate @ into tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a recent question about the show [*@midnight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3279494/) and I was unsure what to use as tagname, given that you cannot use `@`, I settled for the rather easy and generic [midnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midnight). But this seems a bit too generic and inappropriate, given that the `@` is a quite prominent feature and supposed to be spelled *"at"* when reading the title, I guess, in constrast to rather unspelled special characters like `:` or `(`.

I see some alternatives to the plain [midnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midnight), but they all come with their problems:

- [amidnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amidnight) takes a slightly more visual approach but seems a bit "odd".
- [at-midnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/at-midnight) or [atmidnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmidnight) fit better to the read out version but seem like too much translation.

So what would be the best approach in this case?

(Or maybe there is already some policy on this from elsewhere or we can come to a conclusion for other special characters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think [at-midnight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/at-midnight) is clearer and close to the intent of the title.

Comment: But this tag seriously require a description.

Comment: Well, since nobody else chimed in nor voted on anything (surprisingly, given meta's tremendously high activity), I'm going to accepted this and see it as resolved.